# ASP.NET - Cache & Filter or SQL w/ a large results set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a large set of relatively static data (50,000+ rows) that needs to be accessed by a .NET MVC application on a regular basis.  Each call to the data only needs 5-20 rows at a time - filtered on one or 2 columns (usually a "starts with" filter.)

I'm trying to determine if anyone has any information on the performance benefits of using a filtered .NET Dataview (rowfilter) which will be cached vs. hitting the database each time.  Obviously it saves the database - but how efficient are filtered dataviews?  Will I be putting undue stress on my web server?

Comment: What do you mean by a filtered DataView?  Do you mean this is a DataView generated/stored at the application level containing the entire data set (50,000+ rows), that is filtered on the fly for needed data?

Answer (score 2):

A cache should generally be used for small, frequently-accessed bits of data, when the same data is required over and over.  Since you are getting different rows each time from a large dataset, my bet is that the database will be faster at rummaging through 50,000+ rows for a couple of rows if the table is properly indexed.  Best way to tell is to fire up a proof-of-concept for both approaches and compare the speed and amount of memory used between the two approaches, and judge whether each falls in line with your requirements.

Hope this helps!